# how to find the nth highest number when values of the numbers are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**SQL Question:** 
Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table (SQL Server)

```
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
```

For this example, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
```

**My code is the following:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      select distinct a.salary from Employee a, Employee b where
      a.id =b.id-n+1 order by a.id desc
      limit 1
      
  );
END
```

**My question is**: The code works for most of the cases except for the situation when there are multiple same values before the nth place. For example, whe n is 2 and the table is the following. (The expected result should be NULL and my code returns 100. ) So, how can I change my code so that it can work for all situations? Thank you!

```
+----+--------+
| id | salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 100    |
| 3  | 100    |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Is ID sorted by salary already (possibly with ties)?

Comment: id is the primary key for the table, it should be sorted I think?

Comment: You say SQL Server. but tag MySQL. Which dbms are you actually using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    Select distinct salary
   From (
    Select salary, dense_rank() over 
   (order by salary desc) r
   from employee 
    ) where r=n
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st 2nd and 3rd highest salary query**

```
SELECT        MAX(salary) AS ThirdHighestSalary
FROM            emp
WHERE        (salary <
                             (SELECT        MAX(salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
                               FROM            emp
                               WHERE        (salary <
                                                             (SELECT        MAX(salary) AS HighestSalary
                                                               FROM            emp))))
```